# What is the process to officially trade magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league, character-sheets

In D&D Adventurers League, if two players are not playing at the same table, I know that they can still trade magic items if they spend downtime days.

How does this work? Do the players just have to agree that they are trading the items and then they each mark it on their character sheets, or is there some other record that must be created (e.g. the players have to fill out a form?) I know that it used to be that the magic items were on certificates so you would have to physically trade the certificate, but I don't think that they have the certificates any more.

Also, if the players don't have to have the physical certificates, do the players even have to be in the same physical location to do it? Or can two players negotiate a magic item trade completely over the Internet?

Also, can two characters both played by the same player still trade magic items between each other? (Of course they would still have to spend downtime days because the same player can't play two characters at one table) I know that you can't just give your other character a magic item, it has to be a trade, right? Do Potions of Healing count for this - i.e. if I had characters Alice and Bob, and Alice had a magic item that would work really well for Bob's character but Bob didn't have any magic items, I could just have Bob buy a potion of healing and trade it to Alice for the item? Would you be allowed to do that?

Answer (score 6):

The material is covered in the Adventurers' League Player's Guide. It changes each season, so it is best obtained from the [Dungeon Master's Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) as part of the Player's Pack. It's a free download, though you do need to register for the site.

Adventurers' League primarily functions on the honor system. There is no master record that needs to be updated anywhere, just the two character's log sheets.

### Basic Requirements

- Only permanent magic items can be traded; consumables like potions and scrolls cannot be traded (they *can* be shared while at the same table, but if unused, possession reverts to the owner at the end of the session).
- The items to be traded must have matching rarities. If you want a *Rare* item, you have to have a *Rare* item to swap for it. Items without a rarity are considered "unique," and may not be traded.
- Certificates are no longer required, unless the item does not have a published rarity. If the rarity is only established/printed on the certificate, then the certificate must go with the trade. If the player does have a certificate, and it is not required to establish rarity, it must be destroyed or physically handed off.

### Same Table

Players simply swap the magic items and note the change - include the character name, player name, and player's DCI number (if available) and you're all set.

I like to record which adventure or module the player got the item from. They should have all this information on their own adventure log. If they don't, you should be wondering how they got the item to begin with. Plus, some items have special minor functions that are unique to the source - for example, the *Bracers of Archery* from one particular module also provide protection against high and low temperatures. *Bracers of Archery* obtained by other means lack this extra benefit.

### Different Table

Each player deducts 15 downtime from their character and proceed as above. The downtime reflects the characters meeting each other somewhere or working with third-party agents to facilitate the trade.

### Self Trades

If the same player controls both characters, they can never meet at the same table. Conduct the trade like a different table trade - both characters pay the downtime.

<sub>**On Seasons**

This answer was originally written during Season 7. Season 8 added an additional requirement of matching the Magic Item Table from the DMG. As of Season 9, the magic item trading rules have gone back to how they were in Season 7 (minus lifestyle expenses, which I removed the reference to anyway). Who knows what will happen when Season 10 rolls around sometime in late 2020 or early 2021.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

All of this information is covered very succinctly in the [D&D Adventurer's League Player's Guide](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/AL_PH_SKT.pdf), which you really, really should read if you're playing AL.

> **Trading Permanent Magic Items**
>
> Characters are allowed to trade permanent magic items received in official D&D Adventurers League play with one another, or even with themselves (i.e. between two characters of a single player). A certificate is not required to facilitate this trade, but if the item bears a certificate, it must either be traded or destroyed.
>
> If trading with another character playing in the same game session as you, the trade may be completed without expending downtime days. Otherwise, each participant in a given trade must spend 15 downtime days to complete the trade.
>
> Upon completing the trade, an entry must be created on each character's log sheet indicating who they traded with (and their DCI number if they have one), the item traded away, and the item received in exchange. Magic items can't be given away to another character; a permanent magic item must be received in return.
>
> Furthermore, permanent magic items may only be traded for permanent magic items of like rarity (i.e. uncommon for uncommon, rare for rare, etc.). If the item’s rarity is in question, the Dungeon Master’s Guide or other official, published D&D product, is considered to be the deciding resource.